# How to include filter in sheet reference formula (Google Sheets)?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to reference something from Sheet1 to Sheet2. However, I want to include the filter for the rows from Sheet1.

These are the current formulas that work:

> For Getting data based on a filter:

```
=sum(FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5="Filter Name"))
```

> For Referencing Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 (range):

```
=sum(Sheet1!A1:B1)
```

What I want to do is combine both into something like this (but this formula has a parse error):

```
=sum(Sheet1!FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5="Filter Name"))
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Try like `=sum(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5="Filter Name"))`

Comment: Thank you @Harun24HR! This worked :D I experimented with it a little bit too and have a better idea of the formula works. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to know! I have posted as answer so that you can accept it to close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer sheet name in wrong way. Try like below-

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5="Filter Name"))
```